# process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>

Tags: c, windows

i am a beginner to coding and learning c language as my first step.
when i use string function the program returns with a value without showing output. using minGW as compiler

i tried to add string.h header folder
string
from below follows code

```
''''
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    /*
    int strlen(string);
    */
    char name = { 's','i','l','a','m','\0' };

    int length;

    length = strlen(name);
    printf("the length of %s is %d\n", name, length);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
'''
```

code ends here

expected to to print length of the char name but it crashes 
as in build log
"Process terminated with status -1073741819 "
in build messages
warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'|

thanking you for looking into

Comment: Don't you get other warnings as well? Take warnings serious.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You need to define `name` as a `char name[]` not `char name`. `%s` in `printf` expects a string not a char. Plus, you need to `#include <string.h>` for `strlen()`.

Comment: You are using `getch();` which MS deprecates in favour of `_getch();` so you are probably used to seeing warning messages which you ignore. You must satisfy yourself why there are warning messages. Ideally there should be none.

Comment: Never ignore warnings! Besides "warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast" you should also see "warning: excess elements in scalar initializer" Don't even try to run the program as long as you have warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // single char can't store that string
    // so we have to declare an array of chars
    char name[] = {'s', 'i', 'l', 'a', 'm', '\0'}; 
    // also we can use string literal syntax:
    // char name[] = "silam";
    int length = strlen(name);
    printf("the length of %s is %d\n", name, length);
    getc(stdin);
    // i don't have <conio.h> so i call 'getc' instead of 'getch'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `name` as a `char` yet you treat it like an array. To declare `name` as a `char` array, use:

```
char name[] = { 's','i','l','a','m','\0' };
```

Also since you reference the function `strlen()`, you must add the header file:

```
#include <string.h>
```